# Jquery hide dropdown when not hovering over link or dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseleave, mouseout

This is driving me crazy.

I have a navigation and one of the items in the navigation triggers a dropdown to appear underneath the navigation when I hover over the dropdown link.

The navigation and dropdown both share the same parent.

I would like the dropdown to dissapear whenever the cursor is not on the dropdown link OR the dropdown itself. Right now the dropdown is still being shown when the cursor is inside the ul.menu

How do I fix this?

This is the JS

```
    $('.header_navigation a').on('mouseenter', function () {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active_link')) {
        $('.dropdown_container').hide();
        $('.active_link').removeClass('active_link');
        $('.is-absolute').parent().addClass('feature_image');
        $('.mega-nav-desktop__blackout').removeClass('show');
      }
    });     
    
    $('.main-nav .nav, .top-bar, .cart-container').on('mouseleave', () => {
      $('.dropdown_container').hide();
      $('.active_link').removeClass('active_link');
      $('.is-absolute').parent().addClass('feature_image');
      $('body').removeClass('is-active');
      $('.mega-nav-desktop__blackout').removeClass('show');
    });

    $('.dropdown_link').on('mouseover', function () {
      $('.dropdown_container').hide();
        $('.mega-nav-desktop__blackout').addClass('show');

      const $dropdown = $(this).parents('.main-nav').find(`[data-dropdown="${$(this).data('dropdown-rel')}"]`);

      $('.active_link').removeClass('active_link');

      if (!$(this).hasClass('active_link')) {
        $dropdown.show();

        if ($(this).hasClass('mini_cart')) {
          if (!$('body').hasClass('cart')) {
            $(this).parent('.cart-container').addClass('active_link');
          }
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('active_link');
          $('.is-absolute').parent().removeClass('feature_image');
        }
      }
    });
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="nav nav--combined nav--center">
    <ul class="menu header_navigation center">
        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown_link" data-dropdown-rel="dropdown">Dropdown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdown_container mega-menu mega-menu-1" data-dropdown="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown menu">Dropdown comes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6L1h3dr5/1/

Comment: Do you have any CSS?

Comment: Could you add the css so we could try it on jsfiddle.net? I have create a fiddle with your code but I need the css to test further. Tank you https://jsfiddle.net/81fz0pb5/

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Sorry, I have updated the JSfiddle with the CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/6L1h3dr5/1/

Comment: Hi @DaniilVnoutchkov I have used the tutoriel here   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_mega_menu_responsive   to make a full width dropdown has it does not require javascript/jquery. This will reduce the amount of jquery you will have to write. You will just need to add the code that make it darker on hover. Here is the code I have made so far hope this helps you https://jsfiddle.net/y7jsgk4p/

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach thanks for that, but I am searching for how I can fix my current jquery code to accomplish my goal :)

Comment: No problem it is understandable. I hope you will find a solution soon. :)